# Re-order blocks inside bootstrap columns using grid css

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, css-grid

I have two columns and each column contains two blocks

The current order in mobile is 
1
2
3
4

And I want it to be :
3
1
2
4

I tried to use grid but I don't know how I can get block 3 out from column 2.

See:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.block {
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.y{
  background:yellow;
}
.r{
  background:red;
}
.b{
  background:lightblue;
}
.g{
  background:lightgreen;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .container {
    display: grid;
    background-color: pink;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container">
       <div class="col-md-8">
         <div class="block y"> 1</div>
              <div class="block r">2 </div>
       </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="block b"> 3</div>
           <div class="block g">4 </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

And another question can we did this ordering by using CSS supported by IE11? because display:grid is not supported by IE.

Comment: Using CSS-Grid, **you can't**. `order` works on elements in the same parent.

Comment: Is there any way to do that without using js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the layout a little and you will be able to achieve this using bootstrap classes (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#order) without the need of CSS grid:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.block {
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.y {background: yellow;}
.r {background: red;}
.b {background: lightblue;}
.g {background: lightgreen;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 order-1 order-md-0">
      <div class="block y"> 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 order-0 order-md-1">
      <div class="block b"> 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="block r">2 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="block g">4 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With you current code, the only way is to use `display:contents` which is not well supported (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents)

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.block {
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.y {
  background: yellow;
}

.r {
  background: red;
}

.b {
  background: lightblue;
}

.g {
  background: lightgreen;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .container {
    background-color: pink;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    padding:0!important;
  }
  .container > .row,
  .container > .row > div{
    display:contents;
  }
  .b {
    order:-1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="block y"> 1</div>
      <div class="block r">2 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="block b"> 3</div>
      <div class="block g">4 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice using flexbox

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is helpful, but I can't use method 1 because in my case the blocks have different heights and this will affect the desktop view.

Comment: @Duha you can duplicate the 3rd div? I see it the only way to have what you want